# Unload reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got a website, that is lazyloading react scripts from different sources. For each script loaded, we provide a div with the name of the script as id. As soon as the script is loaded, it searches for the div with the id and renders the components.

As the site is displayed on a stationary tablet it does not reload very often and  the memory footprint gets pretty big. Is there a way to completely unload a react script without reloading the website? Is there even a way to just unload any 
kind of script? I guess the garbage collector is responsible for this, but currently its not even removing scripts / components that have unmounted a long time ago.

As I was searching for a solution, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204054/unloading-destroying-angular-lazy-loaded-components) thread about angular. I'm basicly looking for a way to do the same with react (Even tho I didn't test the angular solution).

Comment: Maybe the memory footprint will get smaller if you just render `null` in the component you don't want to display anymore?

Comment: When the component is no longer needed, the script tag and the div it got rendered to, get removed from the dom outside of react. Maybe you are right and we need to render null before removing everything from the dom. I will try this tomorrow, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before removing the script tag and the container DOM node, you can use [`unmountComponentAtNode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) to allow React to do its cleanup.

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a design pattern that uses conditional rendering and check in the componentDidMount if either data is returned or the specific section is to be rendered.